# Navigating back to the previous Fragment not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing a simple app, with several static screens, just. I get working passing from first fragment, but can't go back to any screen ever.
I saw some videos, like [shorturl.at/jFPRY](https://shorturl.at/jFPRY), but in any cases makes work. In my MainActivity I have the OnCreate method, where I save the instance, set the layout, and add a Listener to options on my menu itens.

In the first click, when I open the app, it goes to correct destiny. However, when I click another item it does nothing, stucked. I need to set the Fragments bidirectional, in other words, the user can view any fragment in any moment from any fragment.

My OnCreate method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
    
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_conheca_a_UFTM -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.drawer_layout, ConhecaUftmFragment())
                    .commit()
                // Remove the other operations
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);

            }
            R.id.nav_calendario_academico -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.drawer_layout, GalleryFragment())
                    .commit()
                // Remove the other operations
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
            }
            R.id.nav_mural_de_informacoes -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.drawer_layout, CalendarioFragment())
                    .commit()
                // Remove the other operations
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
            }



        }
        it.isChecked = true
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers()

        true
    }
    supportActionBar?.apply {
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)

    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.appBarMain.toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)

}
```

I have also the method onSupportNavigateUp:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = this.findNavController(id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    return navController.navigateUp()
}
```

And here is an example of Fragment that I have:

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,  container: ViewGroup?,  savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendario_academico, container, false)

        /* view.setOnClickListener(){ Navigation.findNavController(view).
             navigate(R.id.conhecauftmToaprimorando)
         }*/

        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

    }

}
```

I will pass my [GitHub link](https://github.com/NoodleLDS/AprimorandoosConhecimentos), if anyone can help to fix this issue.

Comment: You cannot use `FragmentTransaction` at all when using the Navigation Component. Is there a reason you aren't following the [guide for setting up your navigation drawer with the Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer)?

Answer (score 0):

First approach would be to not use FragmentTransactions when you using NavComponent.
If you have the MenuOptions on the MainActivity layout (which I don't recommend, it should go on every fragment, so the MenuOptions are correlated to the current fragment) you can define your navigations in the nav_graph.xml and use them in the MainActivity through NavigationDirections object.

Please visit https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started for more info.

If you want to come back from GalleryFragment to where you have defined the destination of the Popback behaviour, you should call: `findNavController.popBackStack()`